# Regarding searching a keyword in all files in particular directory in linux

Tags: linux, find

I want to search a word suppose "abcd" in all the files(Including hidden and all possible files) in dir suppose /home/john/? 
This is what I tried, I am running the below command and its getting stuck for more than 24 hours. 
command --> find /home/john -type f -exec grep -iH 'abcd' {} \;

Result something which will show all the files which have this particular word or any file which is have the name as our search word.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using grep recursion option ?

```
grep -r abcd /home/john
```

Comment: Hi this above command is also getting stuck. Also, Will the above command will search for this keyword in hidden files also. I have also used -i flag to match case's.

Comment: Yes it looks in hidden files / dir. How many GB are in your directory ? (du -sh /home/john/) because grep is fast. If you just want filename instead of lines you can use -l flag